# get component inside react-emotion or styled-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

```
import styled from 'react-emotion'

class Field extends React.Component<> {}

export default styled(Field)
```

then if I render this component and use `component.type`, i get `styled()...` function instead of `Field` component.

How I get `Field` inside styled function?

Comment: .type will not even work on Field component that extends React.Component

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import styled from 'react-emotion'

const Field = ({ className }) => (
    <div className={className}>Some field</div>
)

const theField = styled(Field)`
    color: green;
`
export default theField
```

Comment: Was there a bounty on this question or it's just my imagination?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the function is just exporting the function, but I think you want the component. So why not this?

```
import styled from 'react-emotion'

class Field extends React.Component<> {}

const styledField = styled(Field)

export default styledField
```

Comment: Was there a bounty on this question or it's just my imagination?

Comment: i think it was, but as far as i know, they expire after 7 days or so

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't it be assigned to anyone, I don't see anyone got it, how that got avoided?

Comment: as far as i know, if you do not mark an answer as answer, no one gets it...

Answer (score -1):

`styled` library doesn't provide any way to get a Field. Even if it does `Field.type` will be `undefined` since Field doesn't have this property. You can try this code and see:

```
 class Field extends React.Component<> {
  render() {
    return (<div></div>);
  }
}

console.log(Field.type); // this will be 'undefined' not 'div' as you might expect
```